# Cryptsetup login fails after applying proprietary ATI driver (fglrx-updates)

Tags: drivers, ati, encryption, fglrx, cryptsetup

I encrypted my installation of Ubuntu 14.04 while installing it, later I switched the driver of my ATI Radeon HD 6970 to "fglrx-updates". After that I could only close but not open any programs. I guessed that a reboot would help and the Ubuntu cryptsetup login screen looked a lot more primitive (text based). Also I can't login any more. Error message "cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?"

I've done some research and apparently quite a few people face problems with those proprietary drivers, also while booting. For some the cryptsetup login screen looks different too, but I can't even get past the encryption. I'd prefer to not lose the installation, is there a different way than formating and reinstalling?

Comment: Going by the date of your question, this may not be graphics driver related. Over the last week, I have been locked out of my three Ubuntu computers after they updated. One is a Samsung laptop, one is Intel NUC, one is HP Pavilion. Really need an answer to this so will keep in searching.